# 'Where' Query with Rails Arel Table That Matches to an Enum (How to force query as type text)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I am trying to use an arel table to match all instances of a column in my table that match a regular expression. This works easily with strings but when the search field is an enum it does not work.

My code for querying my database is as follows:

```
res = Test::Table
arel_tbl = res.arel_table["spec_type"].parameterize.underscore.to_sym
res = res.where(arel_tbl.matches("%#NewProd%"))
```

So with the above code the query works if my "spec_type" column contains values of type string, but in my instance all of the values under that column are enums, so I need to convert them to text to compare against the regular expression.

An example of an ActiveRecord query that works this way can be seen below:

```
Test::Table.where("spec_type::text like '%NewProd%'")
```

So this query works because I force spec_type to be of type text which allows my SQL query to call LIKE against the regular expression. How can I get the same sort of functionality with an arel table? I want the arel table because it auto quotes my data.

Comment: Couldn't you say `Test::Table.where('spec_type::text like ?', '%NewProd%')` and avoid AREL? Am I missing something?

Comment: Ya I could but then doesn't that open me up to an SQL injection attack? Cause it seems to be Arel quotes the data by default and I don't know how to secure your query as written above

Comment: No, ActiveRecord will properly quote the placeholder's value when it builds the SQL.

Comment: Oh really awesome thanks, could you explain a little more how that helps?

Comment: It helps by avoiding AREL? Maybe it is just me but I find AREL-based code to be an incomprehensible mess.

Comment: The only problem with the non arel query is I am not able to export with just a single quote ' like I was with the arel implementation